# How To Fix Nvim Lsp and mason Json Error In Lua

Tags: lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

When I Setuped Lsp In Nvim This Linter Keeps Showing In Every Language Such As HTML,CSS or even when I Write In Lua

The Error

[image: 1]

Who Should I Do To Solve or hide this error

I tried to lock at the docs but it hasn't any thing and i am expecting solving the error or hiding it from the prompt

Answer (score 0):

After Some Days Of Trying To Fix It.
The Error just Disapperd After I Unstalled json mason plugin for lsp.
I don't know why is the plugin do this but if you have the same problem just uninstall the json plugin lsp.